# Let Mac users unclog print queues

Tags: mac-osx, printing, queue

In one of the schools I work at, I was told that users are having trouble printing -- that the print queues keep getting jammed, and they are prompted for a password that they don't have to unjam them.

Our users are using Macs running OS X 10.5.7.  The computers are printing directly to a network printer (ie. without going through a print server first).

I found out how to determine which machines have problems:

```
lpstat -o -p
```

shows which jobs are in the queue, and states things about the printers.  On a problem computer, it ends with this:

```
printer CJHS_WestLab_HP1320 disabled since Wed Dec 16 09:35:54 2009 -
    /usr/libexec/cups/backend/lpd failed
```

I think the reason that print jobs are failing is because somehow, the printer is defaulting to using size A4 paper -- and students here use US Letter-sized paper exclusively.  The job then goes to the printer, which starts blinking until you hit one button to print anyway, or another to cancel the job.

I have two questions:

- how can I enforce a US Letter page size (in a script?)
- can I let users clear the queue themselves?  enable them to pause and unpause printers?

  - if not, is there a good script to run to purge the queues?

I can see that as an admin, I can purge print jobs in these ways:

- I found [a nice script that'll clear the queues every two minutes](http://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/ClearingStoppedMacPrintQueues) -- but surely there is a more elegant solution to the problem!?  [I'll take something that works over something that is elegant, but elegant + works == goodness].
- And, with just a little more searching ... [cancel -a -](http://chrisgonyea.com/archives/2008/05/26/clear-entire-print-queue-in-os-x-with-a-terminal-command/).  It still prompts for someone who belongs to the lpadmin group, and it doesn't resume stuck printers ... but it is really useful to know, for fixing things as an admin.

I also found this [Mac OS X hint that negates the requirement for users to be in the lpadmin group](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20081107092520601) by editing /etc/cups/cupsd.conf .  This sounds great -- I'm just worried that it'll be stomped on by a software update.

Still, I can't help but feel that there is something I'm overlooking, and that there is a better solution to this problem.  (And I'd love to know why the default page size is A4, and how to fix that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid messing with cupsd.conf (and risking stompage), you can add users to the _lpadmin group:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a fred _lpadmin
```

or just add everyone:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -t group -a everyone _lpadmin
```

BTW, membership in _lpadmin grants both the ability to manage queues, and also configure printer settings; if you just want to grant queue management, I believe you can do that by adding people to _lpoperator instead.

As for avoiding A4, my first thought is to edit the printer's ppd file to remove all mention of the cursed PageSize -- but this is not something I know anything about...

Comment: I take it you've had problems with A4 as well :)

I've been wondering about adding users to the lpadmin group, and wondering if it could be done in workgroup manager.  On my 10.5 machine, there is an _lp and _lpadmin group -- I think _loperator might be new to 10.6.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you meant 'everyone' in the group command literally.  I thought I was supposed to substitute a group in there that has all the users, or most of them.  This has worked really nicely.  Combined with telling the printer (over its web interface) to resise A4-sized documents and print them, I believe I've got my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

for your page size issue i had the oposite problem defaulting to us Letter fixed it with lpadmin

use and lpadmin comand on your printer and add "-o PageSize=*" * being the size you want to default to for example mine would be -o PageSize=A4

run man lpadmin in terminal to get a better look :)

Comment: `lpstat -v` gives the names of all the printers, which can be passed to `lpoptions` or `lpadmin`.  The parameter I want is `-o media=Letter`.  While these commands will change ~/.cups/lpoptions and /private/etc/cups/lpoptions, it does not (appear to) affect how GUI programs print.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to System Preferences -> Print & Fax and change the "Default Paper Size in Page Setup", it writes the change to ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.print.PrintingPrefs.plist .

The parameter can be ready by running

```
defaults read com.apple.print.PrintingPrefs DefaultPaperID
```

and typically returns na-letter or iso-a4.

It can be changed by the specified user by running

```
defaults write com.apple.print.PrintingPrefs DefaultPaperID na-letter
```

I want to manage this preference for my entire lab.  To do this, I selected the computer group in Workgroup Manager, clicked on Preferences (up top) and then on the Details tab on the right.  I then hit the plus button and found my correctly configured ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.print.PrintingPrefs.plist file and went with the default of managing the properties "Often".  I then found com.apple.print.PrintingPrefs in the list and hit the pencil to edit it.  Under the "Often" keys, I deleted everything except the DefaultPaperID, and hit "Apply Now" and "Done".

I've confirmed that the setting takes effect (Apple Menu -> About This Mac -> More Info, and then, when System Profiler comes up, scroll down to "Managed Client" (near the bottom), and see if it shows the setting).  I think it'll work nicely.